# Some text hidden with dots

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We are using Microsoft Bot Framework to build a bot that sends messages formatted as Adaptive Cards. And occasionally on Android devices some symbols in the text become replaced with dots. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot with hidden letters]

We are creating adaptive cards dynamically by using classes `AdaptiveCard`, `AdaptiveTextBlock`, `AdaptiveElement`, `AdaptiveColumnSet` and others. Then we add created attachment to a `turnContext.Activity.Attachment`. These dots disappear on already sent messages after some time. But it doesn't happen always. On other platforms (iOS, Desktop, Web) everything is rendered as expected.

There is a [bug reported in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/6674), that I suppose is related to our bug, But Microsoft guys said that they aren't going to fix it.

Some observations:

1. Dots appear often when we add too much text to adaptive card (greater than 250 symbols per `AdaptiveTextBlock`).
2. Dots appear often on old versions of Android (10 and older).
3. If we don't use a default size of text during creating an adaptive card, but set it manually (for example "medium") then dots arise less often.

The question is obviously how to get rid of these dots on android?

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue and we have raised a bug for the same. We will keep you posted on the updates. Please note that we see dots in Android 11. Dots appears even after setting the size manually.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. We checked the fix at our end, and it is rendering fine.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, thank you, we also check on our side and it works correctly now. But why are you using comments and not answers?? Comments is for clarification of question if I'm not mistaken...